# Mac OS X: How to permanently change the prompt (value of PS1) in the shell of emacs client?

Tags: osx, emacsclient

I have start emacs as daemon through (`emacs --daemon`). I then launch the client (`emacsclient -c`) and use its shell mode through (`M-x shell RET`). However the prompt starts with:

> bash-3.2$

I have changed the value of `PS1` by `export PS1="\w\$ "` in `.bash_profile`. So any idea how to change the value of `PS1` in the shell of emacsclient?

**Edit:** or an equal question is: where does emacsclient get environment variables, e.g. $PATH, $PS1 ...? Knowing this will solve my question.

Answer (score 2):

`.bash_profile` is read only by login shells. Emacs will start a normal interactive shell, which reads from `.bashrc`.

(this isn't really an Emacs question. The bash manpage covers startup in great detail).

Comment: Thanks for reply! Now it works after changing .bashrc. Another problem is after opening the shell in Emacs, the path it is in (shown by "pwd") is different from where I launch the emacsclient. Do you know how to solve this issue? Thank you!

Comment: emacsclient will start in the same directory as where emacs --daemon was invoked. Either do 'emacsclient -c .' or 'emacsclient -c <filename>'

Comment: Hi @rpluim, I understand it should be so. But oddly enough in my case, no matter where I launch 'emacsclient -c', the shell in emacs is always in the root directory, i.e. '/'. Do you know how to solve this issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's a pretty Emacs-specific question IMO.

OP, you can check on the variable INSIDE_EMACS to differentiate, like this:

```
if [[ $INSIDE_EMACS = "" ]]; then
    export CLI_COLOR=1
    export PS1='\e[33m\u\e[m@\e[32m\h\e[m:\e[34m\w\e[m\$ '
else
    # inside Emacs. This can also go inside init_bash.sh if need be. 
    alias ls="ls -FG"
    export TERM=ansi
    # has to match the definition of dirtrack-list (in init.el)
    export PS1='\033[33m\u\033[m@\033[32m\h\033[m:\033[34m\w\033[m\$ \n==> '
fi
```

Comment: If the question had been "how can I set PS1 to be different when using M-x shell", then I'd agree with you, but it wasn't.